# (Probability) Independent Probability Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> A car race is very  dangerous, and a crash can cause serious
> injuries. The league requires that anyone who has a crash to have a
> medical examination before they are  allowed to race again. A
> certain racer has an independent **.04** probability of a crash in a race
>
> a)  What is the probability that he will have his first crash within the
> first 30 races  she runs this season?

My solution

Treating like the lottery problem

Probability of not having a crash
**P(First Crash In 30 Races)** = $.04^{30}$

But this produces the wrong answer since the book says that the answer is $.7061$.

Could someone explain why my approach doesn't work and how to properly go about this problem?

Comment: @ temirzahan :P(crash within 30 races)=1-P(no crash within 30 races$)=1-(0.96)^{30}=0.7061$

Answer (score 1):

What you're calculating is the probability that he will crash in **every** race in the first $30$ races. The probability of a crash in a single race is $.04$, and so $.04^{30}$ represents the probability of getting a crash in every single of the first $30$ races.

Instead, the way to approach this problem is to note that the probability of not crashing in a race is $1 - .04 = 0.96$. To calculate the probability that the racer will have his first crash within the first $30$ races is the same as $1$ minus the probability that he won't have a single crash in the first $30$ races. Do you know where to go from here?

Comment: Yes but 1 - (.96)^30 I get it now but it still feels a bit shaky, are their other ways to approach this problem?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by it feeling shaky. For the kind of question that asks you the probability of the first success being in the first n trials, I strongly recommend doing it this way, and thinking of the probability of getting no failures. If you think about it from the straightforward point of the successes it gets very complicated, as you'll have to sum multiple probabilities. For example, you'll find the probability that the first is a success and sum it to the probability that the first isn't but the second is, and etc....

Comment: This does simplify because it ends up being the sum of a geometric series, and will lead you to the same answer, but it has many extra steps compared to the approach I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compute the probability of not having any crash within the first $30$ races.